# Defining my own preprocessor directives in F#

Tags: .net, f#, fsi

I have an F# script that I intend to use both at home and at work. The script shall work similarly in both places, yet, I have a set of issues to deal with at work (mostly regarding firewalls and http proxies) so I'd like to run my script in a slightly different way in one case and in the other.

I imagine that ideally I'd set a special flag (directive) at the FSI level, so I could have `#if AT_WORK` to deal with some sharp corner cases.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can define your own symbols to use with conditional compilation, when you call FSI do it like this:

```
Fsi.exe --define:AT_WORK yourScript.fsx
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233172.aspx

Comment: Also, is there a way to do that by code? Something like #define AT_WORK.

Comment: You could have a wrapper fsx script that does whatever is needed to figure out if your at work or not and then that script launches Fsi.exe with AT_WORK or AT_HOME using Process.Start :-)